# MS Access I have a forms which is not bound to data but holds a option group selector which chooses a field to sort a subform which is datasheet view

Tags: ms-access, subform

```
Private Sub frSortBy_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
 
 Select Case frSortBy
 Case 1
Me![Age].Form.OrderBy = "Age"  ' Sort by two fields.
Me![Age].Form.OrderBy = True
 Case 2
 Me.OrderBy = "HT" ' Sort by descending date.
 Case 3
 Me.OrderBy = "WT" ' Sort by two fields.
 Case 4
 Me.OrderBy = "Salary DESC" ' Sort by descending date.
  End Select
 
 Me.OrderByOn = True ' Apply the sort order.
 'DoCmd.Requery

 Exit Sub
 
'ErrorHandler:
' MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens when code runs - error message, wrong result, nothing? Edit your question.

Comment: Looks like "OrderBy = True" should be OrderByOn. The OrderByOn at end is not applying to subform.